# Significado de "sinrazón" en "Don Quijote"

Tags: traducción, significado

[En otro sitio, EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/367002/interpreting-a-quote-from-don-quixote/367023?noredirect=1#comment856753_367023), estamos platicando acerca del uso de la palabra ***sinrazón*** en el Capitulo 1 de Don Quijote y su traducción en Ingles.

> La **razón** de la **sinrazón** que a mi **razón** se hace, de tal manera mi **razón** enflaquece, que con **razón** me quejo de la vuestra hermosura, y también cuando leía: los altos cielos que de vuestra divinidad divinamente con las estrellas se fortifican, y os hacen merecedora del merecimiento que merece la vuestra grandeza.

Sin duda,  Don Q está loco como cabra, pero la pregunta es como interpretar  “***sinrazón***” y relacionarlo con los otros usos de ***razón***.

Tenemos dos traducciones:

> The reason for the ***unreason*** to which my reason ***is subjected***, so weakens my reason that I have reason to complain of your beauty.
>
> The reason for the ***madness which assails*** my reason does weaken it, [and] I have not lost my reason in complaining of your beauty.

## sinrazón

El [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XzJyNwM) tiene...

> Acción hecha contra justicia y fuera de lo razonable o debido.

Pero en mi parte del mundo significa...

> 1. Acción o cosa ilógica o irracional

Ej. Aquel despido fue una sinrazón

> 2. Falta de razón o lógica en una cosa

Ej. La  sinrazón de su comportamiento me preocupa.

Sinónimos incluyen:

> Injusticia, error, arbitrariedad, atropello, contrasentido, ilegalidad, abuso, parcialidad, despotismo, locura

¿Entonces, en la citación de Cervantes la palabra sinrazón significa locura, atropello, abuso, todos, o tal vez algo más? ¿Cual fuel la intención de Cervantes?

Answer (score 6):

He buscado [otras referencias a esa cita](https://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/Discusi%C3%B3n:Raz%C3%B3n), para tener algo más de contexto. Básicamente, Cervantes nos describe a Quijote, al que le gustaba tanto leer que descuida su hacienda y las tareas propias de su estatus social (la caza), e incluso malvende parte de sus tierras para comprar más libros.

Dice Cervantes que Quijote

> llevó a su casa todos cuantos pudo haber ellos [libros]; y de todos ningunos le parecían tan bien como los que compuso el famoso Feliciano de Silva: porque **la claridad de su prosa, y aquellas intrincadas razones suyas, le parecían de perlas**;

Y la "clara prosa" e "intrincadas razones" son son otras que esa cita de `La razón de la sinrazón que a mi razón se hace...` que nos trae de cabeza y que por cierto causa la locura de Don Quijote.

Según [este ensayo](http://digitalcommons.providence.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1072&context=inti), Cervantes se burla de Feliciano de Silva en esa cita, implicando que Alonso Quijano se vuelve loco de leer tanto libro de Silva:

> Silva's romances are named as those which contributed most to Don Quijote's insanity because of the style exemplified in the famous "razón de la sinrazón" phrase.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feliciano_de_Silva) sostiene lo mismo.

Así que primer punto, es una cita del Quijote, pero los versos son originales de Francisco de Silva (hay una cita en esa cita), y la intención de Cervantes es burlarse de la prosa de Silva. Y se burla precisamente de que **es difícil de entender** ("clara prosa", se mofa Cervantes, que lleva a Alonso Quijano a la locura). Se burla de que es una tontería de las típicas que se escribían en los libros de caballería de la época y que pretende ser profunda (y sin embargo es un sinsentido).

En cuanto a una posible traducción, teniendo en cuenta que la frase es difícil de entender y posiblemente ambigua a propósito, yo favorecería `unreason`, para mantener esa [aliteración](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliteraci%C3%B3n) de razón-sinrazón-razón-razón-razón que creo que era la intención original de Silva, y que no se mantendría con `madness` u otras posibilidades. El significado poco importa, si hacemos caso a Cervantes, y me da que Silva no le dio mucha importancia tampoco.

Comment: In other words, debating the meaning of the uasge is probably pointless as the passage was probably ambiguous and  meant to deliberately mock de Siva and confuse the reader. All was an exercise in futility, and we are driving ourselves crazy over the same thing that drove Don Q mad? Also @tchrist

Comment: @Cascabel, I think would need to ask Silva about the original intention, but I agree with Cervantes that Silva would not be able to provide a good answer. It seems he just wanted to sound "cool or smart"  but the phrase is empty in sense snd meaning. That's why I proposed a translation focusing on keeping the alliteration and the "(un)reason" word rather than trying to understand the real meaning.

Comment: @Cascabel To think that _sinrazón_ have more meanings is precisely overcomplicate it, and more important, it's unnecessary. The point in that phrase is precisely that writers like _Silva_ didn't wrote complex books full of meanings, but only decorated and redecorated really simple plots and stories. The phrase literally is saying that *she is so beatiful that drives him mad*. Only that and nothing more. That's precisely where _Cervantes_ "put" the irony and criticism about writers like _Silva_, and of course the madness of Quijote who copy that books style like if it were something great.

Comment: @Cascabel No, obviously only that alliteration can't drove mad anyone. That's not the thing, supposedly sorcery(sorcery, witchcraft, magic, I'm not sure what would be the correct translation) books drove Quijote mad, and that was the style of those books, not alliterations but "to say nothing with a lot of decoration". The alliteration is only one artifact taken from the books, to make the irony and the criticism. By the way, I haven't looked at the book in a lot of years too, but the criticism against that age's sorcery books is a central argument of _El Quijote_, repeated again and again.